# Any way to use elements of FQL attachment media array in multiquery?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

I need to get the list of comments for each item in a user's news feed *including* comments for any media in the feed items.

I'm trying to avoid multiple FQL query roundtrips, so I'd like to use multiquery.

I can get the comments for each post_id in the feed:

```
{
  posts: 'SELECT post_id, attachment FROM stream WHERE filter_key = "nf"',
  post_comments: 'SELECT post_id, fromid, text FROM comment WHERE post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM #posts)'
}
```

However, there doesn't seem to be a way to reference content in the media elements so I can request the comments for media fbids, e.g.:

```
  photo_comments: 'SELECT object_id, fromid, text FROM comment WHERE object_id in (SELECT attachment.media.fbid FROM #posts)'
```

This question ([How to query FQL Stream by Attachment.Media.Type?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12626212/how-to-query-fql-stream-by-attachment-media-type)) is very similar, but the answer was a bit uncertain & wasn't accepted.

Any suggestions or definitive answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figures -- once I posted the question, I came across an answer to another question (http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8003581/get-photos-from-stream) that gave me what I needed:

```
photo_comments: 'SELECT object_id, fromid, text from comment where object_id in (SELECT attachment.media.photo.fbid from #posts)'
```

The example in my answer was a generic description, but turned out to be close to the actual technique (with the photo object missing in the path).

Hope this helps somebody else doing a similarly narrow search.